# Include only a set of folders in generated artifact

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a Desktop application whose structure is like this:

[image]

The default template created a `Copy Files` task like this:

[image]

The problem is that the published artifact **includes all the binaries generated in all the folders**. I don't want that. I only want to include the ones inside 2 folders
- `Deployer.Lumia.Console`
- `Deployer.Lumia.Gui`

Those are the 2 tools inside my Solution (they generate .exe files)

I have tried creating 2 different task like this:

[image]

But I keep getting this error:

[image]

The sources are get from GitHub from this project https://github.com/WoA-project/WOA-Deployer

Every project is inside the \Source folder. So I don't know why it says it cannot be found.

What I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: I've edited my answer to give an illustration of the resulting directory structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error about `../Deployer.Lumia.Gui/bin/**` because the **Source Folder** parameter doesn't support wildcards.

Use your wildcard minimatch pattern to filter the desired files & folders in the `Contents` edit box.

### Get content into stage

To get the content of only those two folders into a directory under the artifact staging directory set up a single copy task as shown...
[image]

### Keep contents separate in stage

If the contents of the ..Gui and ..Console directories need to stay separate in the stage dir, then your use of two separate copy tasks is the simple and straight forward way to go.
[image]
[image]

### Edit 2.0

#### Here is an example of one of our package builds

We are copying the `.dll` files into a /libraries location in stage dir. Notice the wildcard in the contents that captures the directory structure `**\bin\*.dll`.
[image]

Then we are publishing that dir as its own artifact.
[image]

This publish task creates an artifact that looks like this...
[image]

But this build also publishes packages as a separate artifact.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can I use 2 different Publish Artifact Tasks using a special "PathtoPublish" to do what I want? If it's not possible to generate an artifact with both Console+GUI, it would be also OK to generate 2 artifacts, one for Console and another for GUI, but how?

Comment: If you are using the 2 copy tasks to put bin files into sub-dirs of the artifact stage dir, then one publish artifact task on the entire stage dir will include both sets of bin files in their respective directories $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/gui & $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/console. This would result in a `drop/gui` and `drop/console` structure with `Console+GUI` in the same artifact. That sounds like what you want. Separate tasks can be used to target the stage sub directories individually, if 2 artifacts is what you need.

Comment: Opps, broken build: I'm getting this Unhandled: Not found SourceFolder: C:\Source\Deployer.Lumia.Gui\bin\release\

Comment: I've edited the Source Folder, removing the leading "\" and it works now!

Comment: Yep, sorry about that leading slash. I forget if the default working directory variable includes it or not. Apparently it does and the leading slash was taking you to the root or home directory as in a bash prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I think your script should be:

```
$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)/**/Deployer.Lumia.Gui/bin/*
```

that should narrow it down, otherwise you can use a custom script task with something like `ls -Rd` to discover directory structure and adjust your path.

Comment: Ouch, I got this: Unhandled: Not found SourceFolder: D:\a\1\s\**\Deployer.Lumia.Gui\bin\release\* The funny thing is that there IS that folder inside. I have checked the directory structure and it's "D:\a\1\s\Source\Deployer.Lumia.Gui"